# NetSuite : Why? The stock ledger is not equal to the Balance Sheet and/or General Ledger's Inventory Account balance

Tags: netsuite

Why? The stock ledger is not equal to the Balance Sheet and/or General Ledger's Inventory Account balance.

Answer (score 0):

If a Journal is created that performs a credit or debit on the Stock account, it will not be reflected in the Stock Ledger report.  To make a change to the Stock Ledger an alternative method needs to be used, such as :

- Stock adjustments
- Inventory Revaluations
- Transfer orders